# How to solve "Mismatched entity and/or field definitions", specifically, "The URL alias field needs to be installed"?

Tags: database, migrations, 9

After migrating from 7.89 to 9.3.12 this warning appears:

ENTITY/FIELD DEFINITIONS Mismatched entity and/or field definitions
The following changes were detected in the entity type and field definitions.
File
The URL alias field needs to be installed.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Note: Also asked at https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3279976, which I closed because this is actually a better place for support.

Comment: Please post complete steps to reproduce this situation.

Comment: go into new site and the error above is listed in Configuration.....the links to audio files which worked fine in 7.89 are not populated in 9.3.12....you can usually click on the link and it plays the audio file.....

Comment: That is not steps to reproduce.

Comment: It came up after the upgrade....no way to reproduce it short of doing another upgrade....

Answer (score 2):

This issue can only happen if you have two modules installed at the same time. Pathauto and File Entity. It is rare that you need File Entity in Drupal 9 because we have now Media entities. You are probably still using it because you've used it in Drupal 7. But it is very rare that you need the field "URL alias" in the File entity. See https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity/issues/2655844#comment-14212446

So try out this patch to remove this field:

https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity/issues/2655844#comment-14213753